# What users parameters are passed to the front-end from the server in MEAN Stack?

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js, mean-stack

I am using [the MEAN stack](http://mean.io/) and I have this doubt:

Currently, inspecting in the angularjs plugin for chrome, after logged in, in the global scope appears my user information as this:

```
user: { 
    provider: local
    name: Usertest
    email: usertest@usertest.com
    username: User
    _id: 52f94e49088c92d972163f64
    __v: 0
    role: special_member
}
```

As you can see, I have added the field `role` to the user schema.

My question is: why the new role field appears in the front-end, while, for example, password doesn't show up? (I understand it is not expected to appear, but in which file or where is it explicit that some fields should not be passed to the angular managed front-end?).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The user is transferred to Angular in **app/views/index.html:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.user = {{user|safe}};
</script>
```

That `{{ user|safe }}` is passed to the template in **app/controllers/index.js:**

```
res.render('index', {
    user: req.user ? JSON.stringify(req.user) : 'null'
});
```

You could intercept the user here to only pass along certain values:

```
user: req.user ? JSON.stringify({ username: req.user.username, _id: req.user._id }) : 'null'
```

Comment: I have just realized a new commit made 6 days ago which has changed the rendering engine from jade to html. In the old mean boilerplate, based on jade, which is the one i have my app, i can't find the user being passed from the server to the front-end. I have been searching, namely in the views for {{user|safe}}, but haven't found yet.

Comment: I think in jade it would be `window.user = #{user};`

Comment: I have just found it: the user is being passed in the index.jade as window.user = !{user}; . Can you tell me what means the !{user}? exclamation point before the {user} Must be the same as {{user|safe}}, but what's that safe definition?

Comment: That designates that it doesn't need to be cleaned in any way, that it is _safe_ from SQL injection (and other things...?). If the variable were user input, you would not want to use `safe` because the user could do something malicious with the input.